# How do I generate .onion hostnames using PHP?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services

PHP can be used to generate a lot of addresses and private keys for use with Bitcoin. How about Tor? Can we use PHP to generate a Tor hostname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about 'specific' urls (or custom urls), so
to do this with PHP you can let php interface for example [Scallion](https://github.com/lachesis/scallion) on the server you serve php from (or forward the commands to another computer).
I have never seen a 'pure' php way of doing it.

If you just mean random onion domains, then you can let php interface tor through php\python with this library [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/api.html).
Let that generate the domains\keys through php commands triggering python.